# Non-OEM Canon batteries for 5DMIII

Tags: canon, battery, canon-5d-mark-iii

I couldn't resist and bought a bunch of Wasabi LP-E6 lithium batteries for my 5DMIII. They are much cheaper than Canon counterpart.
Now, regardless of whether they keep the charge better or not than Canons (for which different people seem to have different opinion), will there be any technical or functional issue (or potential damage) in using non-OEM batteries?